# is "end" the old-fashion past participle as en in taken?

Tags: grammar, past-participles

I have noticed the shape of `dividend`, `augend`, `mimuend`.
Is `end` the old-fashioned past participle as `en` in `taken`?

I looked it up in Oxford Orgin

> late 15th cent. (in the general sense ‘portion, share’): from
>   Anglo-Norman French dividende, from Latin dividendum ‘something to be
>   divided’, from the verb dividere ‘force apart, remove’.

Which does not state it very clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is a Latin suffix, formed from a Latin gerund.  You can see the more complete suffix in words like "referendum".  In the transfer through French, the -endum has become -end.

It might be worth noting that "dividend" is not a common word (meaning a share of the profits), and "augend" or "minuend"  are exceedingly rare, even in mathematical usage.